# Possible to get included file path?

Tags: luatex, external-files

I know that I can check if a file exists with `\IfFileExists{}{}{}`. Is it also possible to get the absolute path to that found file?

The reason I am asking is that I have a custom documentclass that has an images subfolder with some SVG files. I don't want to copy those files to all the projects that use that documentclass. And to include the SVGs I have:

```
\newcommand{\includesvg}[2]{%
    \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
        \def\svgwidth{\linewidth}%
    \fi%
    \filemodCmp{#1#2.svg}{\the\output@directory/#2.pdf}{%
        \ShellEscape{inkscape -z -D --file=#1#2.svg --export-pdf=\the\output@directory/#2.pdf --export-latex}%
        \input{#2.pdf_tex}%
    }{%
        \input{#2.pdf_tex}%
    }%
}
```

which is then used like this: `\includesvg{images/animals/}{cat}`. But the argument in `inkscape --file=#1#2.svg` is relative to the current directory. So I need to prepend the correct absolute path. Any ideas?

I am using LuaLaTeX, so if I need to use Lua, I'd be fine with that, too.

If it is not possible, I may try to copy the image to `\output@directory`, but then I will have to deal with a flattened directory tree, which I'd rather not at this point in time.

Comment: If you want to use the images in several projects: a) I would convert them to pdf only one time and not each time you are compiling b) put them in a folder where they can automatically found by laetx, e.g. in your texmf folder, then you don't have to deal with paths at all

Comment: With luatex you can use the function `lfs.currentdir ()`, but as @samcarter writes, it is odd that you don't convert the files directly.

Comment: I was thinking about that briefly but didn't go down that route because I didn't want to clutter up the `images` directory with those files. Thinking about it again, I guess I could simply add a `gen` directory with the images hierarchy in there and write the pdfs into that...

Comment: Alright, that worked. I had to modify `\includesvg` as well so that it works on local SVGs. However, @UlrikeFischer: how is `lfs.currentdir()` supposed to help? It is a `pwd` only, it doesn't give me the dir of the last include, or does it?